# Java api to get list of consumers from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to get list of consumers from Kafka from java application? Currently I am just executing shell script following way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list)
```

But it seems wrong. So far I didn't any other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I faced the same issue I used the following from scala and converted to Java:

```
scala.collection.immutable.List<GroupOverview> consumerList = getAdminClient().listAllConsumerGroupsFlattened();
```

The GroupOverview object will give you all details you need for a start.